# Php json_decode не разбирает json из 1с

Tags: php, json

1с передает скрипту json
я сохранил его для теста и пытаюсь понять почему не разбирает
Пробовал его в форму вставлять и отправлять постом - тогда он принимает другой вид и разбирается - каретка заменяется на две их \r\n{\r\n\"\

```
$json = '"[\r\n{\r\n\"\u0412\u0438\u0434\u0414\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0430\": \"\u0417\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0437\u041f\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043f\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044f\",\r\n\"\u041c\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0438\u0432\u0414\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u043e\u0432\": [\r\n{\r\n\"\u041d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440\": \"Chip-001789\",\r\n\"\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430\": \"2021-07-31T12:35:47\",\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0433\u0435\u043d\u0442\": {\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0433\u0435\u043d\u0442\": \"\u0412\u043b\u0430\u0434\u0438\u043c\u0438\u0440 \u0427\u0435\u043b\u0435\u043d\u044e\u043a \",\r\n\"\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0444\u043e\u043d\": \"0955331057\",\r\n\"\u042d\u043b\u041f\u043e\u0447\u0442\u0430\": \"\",\r\n\"\u0414\u043e\u043b\u0433\": 0\r\n},\r\n\r\n\"\u0421\u0443\u043c\u043c\u0430\u0414\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0430\": 580,\r\n\"\u0422\u0430\u0431\u043b\u0438\u0447\u043d\u0430\u044f\u0427\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c\": [\r\n{\r\n\"ID\": \"10b59d10-c399-11eb-81be-901b0e2ad348\",\r\n\"\u041d\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435\": \"\u041c\u043e\u043d\u0438\u0442\u043e\u0440 17\\\" Samsung 710n\",\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u0434\": \"ip-00000930\",\r\n\"\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0430\": 500,\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e\": 1\r\n},\r\n{\r\n\"ID\": \"7a35a5c8-4e70-11eb-a025-901b0e2ad348\",\r\n\"\u041d\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435\": \"\u041a\u0430\u0431\u0435\u043b\u044c \u043f\u0438\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f (\u0440\u043e\u0437\u0435\u0442\u043a\u0430\/\u0441\u0438\u0441\u0442. \u0431\u043b\u043e\u043a) 1.8m PC-186-6\",\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u0434\": \"ip-00000224\",\r\n\"\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0430\": 30,\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e\": 1\r\n},\r\n{\r\n\"ID\": \"7a35a669-4e70-11eb-a025-901b0e2ad348\",\r\n\"\u041d\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435\": \"\u0423\u043f\u0430\u043a\u043e\u0432\u043a\u0430 \u043a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0431\u043a\u0430 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0441\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0435\u043c\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0431\u043b\u043e\u043a\u0430 ChipChip\",\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u0434\": \"ip-00000385\",\r\n\"\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0430\": 50,\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e\": 1\r\n}\r\n]\r\n},\r\n{\r\n\"\u041d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440\": \"Chip-001792\",\r\n\"\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430\": \"2021-07-31T16:17:27\",\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0433\u0435\u043d\u0442\": {\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0433\u0435\u043d\u0442\": \"\u0421\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439 \u0412\u043e\u0432\u043a \",\r\n\"\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0444\u043e\u043d\": \"0688184069\",\r\n\"\u042d\u043b\u041f\u043e\u0447\u0442\u0430\": \"pavel.borysenko@gmail.com\",\r\n\"\u0414\u043e\u043b\u0433\": 0\r\n},\r\n\r\n\"\u0421\u0443\u043c\u043c\u0430\u0414\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0430\": 5550,\r\n\"\u0422\u0430\u0431\u043b\u0438\u0447\u043d\u0430\u044f\u0427\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c\": [\r\n{\r\n\"ID\": \"7a3c6fad-8af7-11eb-9a3c-901b0e2ad348\",\r\n\"\u041d\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435\": \"\u041a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u044c\u044e\u0442\u0435\u0440 HP ProDesk 600 G1: Intel Core i5, 4 Gen, Intel HD, Slim-Desktop-SFF\",\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u0434\": \"ip-00000706\",\r\n\"\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0430\": 4050,\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e\": 1\r\n},\r\n{\r\n\"ID\": \"7a35a545-4e70-11eb-a025-901b0e2ad348\",\r\n\"\u041d\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435\": \"\u0412\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043e\u043a\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0430 GeForce GT710 1Gb GDDR5 Asus (GT710-SL-1GD5-BRK) \u0411\/\u0423 \",\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u0434\": \"ip-00000093\",\r\n\"\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0430\": 1500,\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e\": 1\r\n}\r\n]\r\n}\r\n]\r\n},\r\n{\r\n\"\u0412\u0438\u0434\u0414\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0430\": \"\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0445\u043e\u0434\u043d\u0430\u044f\u041d\u0430\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434\u043d\u0430\u044f\",\r\n\"\u041c\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0438\u0432\u0414\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u043e\u0432\": [\r\n{\r\n\"\u041d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440\": \"Chip-001849\",\r\n\"\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430\": \"2021-07-31T12:35:52\",\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0433\u0435\u043d\u0442\": {\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0433\u0435\u043d\u0442\": \"\u0412\u043b\u0430\u0434\u0438\u043c\u0438\u0440 \u0427\u0435\u043b\u0435\u043d\u044e\u043a \",\r\n\"\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0444\u043e\u043d\": \"0955331057\",\r\n\"\u042d\u043b\u041f\u043e\u0447\u0442\u0430\": \"\",\r\n\"\u0414\u043e\u043b\u0433\": 0\r\n},\r\n\"\u0417\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0437\": \"Chip-001789\",\r\n\"\u0421\u0443\u043c\u043c\u0430\u0414\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0430\": 580,\r\n\"\u0422\u0430\u0431\u043b\u0438\u0447\u043d\u0430\u044f\u0427\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c\": [\r\n{\r\n\"ID\": \"10b59d10-c399-11eb-81be-901b0e2ad348\",\r\n\"\u041d\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435\": \"\u041c\u043e\u043d\u0438\u0442\u043e\u0440 17\\\" Samsung 710n\",\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u0434\": \"ip-00000930\",\r\n\"\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0430\": 500,\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e\": 1\r\n},\r\n{\r\n\"ID\": \"7a35a5c8-4e70-11eb-a025-901b0e2ad348\",\r\n\"\u041d\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435\": \"\u041a\u0430\u0431\u0435\u043b\u044c \u043f\u0438\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f (\u0440\u043e\u0437\u0435\u0442\u043a\u0430\/\u0441\u0438\u0441\u0442. \u0431\u043b\u043e\u043a) 1.8m PC-186-6\",\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u0434\": \"ip-00000224\",\r\n\"\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0430\": 30,\r\n\"\u041a\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e\": 1\r\n},\r\n{\r\n\"ID\": \"7a35a669-4e70-11eb-a025-901b0e2ad348\",\r\n\"\u041d\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435\": \"\u0423\u043f\u0430\u043a\u043e\u0432\u043a\u0430 \u043a\u043e\u0440"';

    $arr = json_decode($json,true);
```

Comment: ничего непонятно. вы можете привести здесь пример **той json строки**, которая "не разбирается"?

Comment: @Ипатьев Все понятно, там элементарная причина.

Comment: @UKRman можете подсказать какая там причина, а то я уже три дня мучаюсь

Answer (score 0):

При передачах данных с 1с в формате JSON используется следующий подход/код к примеру:

```
HTTPСоединение = Новый HTTPСоединение("localhost");
HTTPЗапрос = Новый HTTPЗапрос("/from1c.php"); 
HTTPЗапрос.Заголовки.Вставить("Content-type", "application/json");
HTTPЗапрос.УстановитьТелоИзСтроки(СтрокаJSON, КодировкаТекста.UTF8, ИспользованиеByteOrderMark.НеИспользовать); // А вот и наш недостающий параметр "ИспользованиеByteOrderMark.НеИспользовать"

Ответ = HTTPСоединение.ОтправитьДляОбработки(HTTPЗапрос);

Сообщить("Код результата: " + Ответ.КодСостояния);
Сообщить("Ответ: " + Ответ.ПолучитьТелоКакСтроку("UTF-8"));
```

Детальней можете прочитать [тут](https://infostart.ru/public/619416/), и как описано в [статье](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xXVb.png):

> Обратите внимание, что необходимо указывать «ИспользованиеByteOrderMark.НеИспользовать» иначе возникнут проблемы на стороне сайта с расшифровкой JSON строки.

Вы можете сами провалидировадь JSON, который приходит с 1с, на даном [сайте](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) и увидите что он не валидный. Нужно запросить 1с подправить код, так как на стороне сайта у нас не получиться отформатировать JSON.

Comment: Но JSON который вы сохраняете в лог проходит валидацию?

Comment: я отредактировал свой вопрос вверху я выложил новый json который приходит с 1с и я сохраняю его в файл. Если посмотреть в онлайн сервисах то он разбирается но они к нему какие то каретки добавляют

Comment: ```$json = stripslashes(trim(file_get_contents('Файл, где храниться пример ответа в джейсоне в формате строки.'))); 
$json = filter_var($data, FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);```
Хорошо  попробуйте код выше перед кодом декодирования

Comment: не помогло - возвращает null

Comment: У вас в примере json не верный https://i.imgur.com/jfLduzp.png нет закрывающего тегам